# Better way to add extra attributes in RBAC (Role Based Access Control) tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have implemented RBAC (Role Based Access Control) tables. I have a requirement to add extra attribute on some roles, like `2nd_pwd` attribute in `Admin` role, `address` attribute in `Customer` role.

I have done this design, but it violates data integrity. When you removed (let's say) `Admin` role, you also need to remove admin data from `Admin` table. So I decided to add trigger for this job.

Question:

1. Is there a design for this requirement without trigger but still doesn't violate data integrity?
2. What is the common implementation for this requirement? Is it normalized enough?

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIOyp.png)

Thank you.

Comment: What about some nullable columns for those attributes in the `Group` table? Or a JSON column to have variable attributes?

Comment: @joanolo How about normalized table with less nullable attribute?

Comment: IMHO: An unnecessary complication.

Comment: @joanolo yeah it's complicated, but It's more complicated if I have 10 groups, and each group has 10 additional attributes, and all is stored in `Group` table.

Comment: updated the description.